# python string formatting single quotes and double quotes

Tags: python, string, formatting, single-quotes

I have a variable state = 'PA'. I am trying to generate a string as follows. I would like add single quotes on the state within a string. Also, I want to use this .format method because I will change this state later.

'select * from table where "state" = 'PA''

Currently, I could only be able to generate this
'select * from table where "state" = PA'

using the following code:

```
'select * from table where "state" = {}'.format(state)
```

Comment: Why not "select * from table where state = '{}'".format(state) ?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But I will need double quotes on the state also inside the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can escape the single quotes around the format specifier like this:

```
>>> s = 'select * from table where "state" = \'{}\''.format(state)
>>> print(s)
select * from table where "state" = 'PA'
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That resolved the issue. When I just enter s, it shows something different. But if I used print(s), it shows the string that I needed. And also it runs well.